# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a elementos específicos de un arreglo de strings en php?

Tags: php, array

Tengo un problema al momento de querer contar elementos de un arreglo de strings que solamente contengan un parámetro.

Por ejemplo:

- Ejemplounotemp
- Ejemplodostemp
- Ejemplotrestemp
- Ejemplocuatrotemp
- Ejemplouno
- Ejemplodos
- Ejemplotres

Todos siendo elementos de un arreglo de strings, necesito contar solamente los que tengan *"temp"*; uso `substr` de PHP, pero no funciona.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Itera el array y sobre cada elemento usa [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strrpos.php) para saber si tiene la cadena *'temp'*. Ejemplo: `if(strpos($item, "temp") >= 0)) { $counter++; }`.

Answer (score 1):

La función [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) devuelve un trozo de una cadena, no busca la coincidencia de una cadena dentro de otra.

Para ello debes usar [`strstr()`](http://php.net/strstr), [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) o, con mucha más flexibilidad, [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg-match):

```
$cadenas = [
  'Ejemplounotemp',
  'Ejemplodostemp',
  'Ejemplotrestemp',
  'Ejemplocuatrotemp',
  'Ejemplouno',
  'Ejemplodos',
  'Ejemplotres',
];
$cuenta = 0;
foreach ($cadenas as $cadena) {
  if (strpos($cadena, 'temp') !== false) {
    $cuenta++;
  }
}
echo 'Coincidencias: ', $cuenta, PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! me sirvió de maravilla...no tenia idea de como resolverlo.

Comment: De nada, un placer :)

Answer (score 0):

Recorre el array y usa

```
strpos($lista[$i], 'temp');
```

El primer parámetro es el elemento del array a comprobar y el segundo la palabra a buscar.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías resolverlo usando:

- [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php): para aplicar una función a cada valor del arreglo.
- [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-sum.php): para sumar todos los valores de un arreglo.
- [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php): para detectar si una subcadena esta dentro de una cadena.

Ejemplo:

```
// $array es un array de string
$total = array_sum(array_map(function($string) {
  return strpos($string, 'temp') !== false ? 1 : 0;
}, $array));

echo $total;
```

O también:

- [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-reduce.php): para iterar un array  y reducirlo a un solo valor usando una función.

Ejemplo:

```
$total = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $string) {
  return $carry + (strpos($string, 'temp') !== false ? 1 : 0);
});
```